# Create a custom pattern in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create a pattern in QGIS that could look like a wall with several bricks but I'm not quite sure I understood the custom dash pattern tool.

When I try to do something like this, the pattern never gets perfect, see the image below. Is there anyone who could advise me something?

[image: Result]

Comment: A bit more information on what you actually did you be nice. Did you create an SVG? Have you used a linear pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the brick symbol or create your own symbol using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) open source software and save the image as SVG, then use `Layer Properties -> Style` and change the `Simple fill` to `Raster image fill`, as you can see below:

[image]

You can control the image width as you like depending on your preference.